# How to use scala class JavaDStreamKafkaWriter in Java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven

I am using Maven project within eclipse. It will not compile.

```
JavaRDDKafkaWriter<String> writer = JavaRDDKafkaWriterFactory.fromJavaRDD(inrdd);
writer.writeToKafka(producerConf, new ProcessingFunc());
```

JavaDStreamKafkaWriter class cannot be resolved to a type. I have included the maven dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudera.spark.streaming.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-kafka-writer</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

See https://github.com/cloudera/spark-kafka-writer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly same thing by first downloading source from https://github.com/cloudera/spark-kafka-writer then building snapshot locally. This created jars in my local maven repsoitory.

For DStream code would be

```
 final Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.put("metadata.broker.list","localhost:9092");
 properties.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");

 final JavaDStreamKafkaWriter<String> writer =
        JavaDStreamKafkaWriterFactory.fromJavaDStream(JavaDStream);

  writer.writeToKafka(properties, msg -> new KeyedMessage<>(TOPIC,msg));
```

Comment: Thanks. It compiles, now I hope I can get it to work.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you paste your code? It might be you need to declare some variable static  or inside brodcasting variables so that Writer can access it. What object you are sending to KafkaWriter from Dstream? You might get answer of your doubt in my question :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840210/spark-dstream-writing-to-kafka-not-sending-actual-uuids-to-kafkaconsumer-in-meso